# How can I dismiss a login view if the login was successful? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, dismiss

In my AppDelegate, I use the following code to pop up a login screen if the user is not logged in:

```
let mainSB : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialVC : UIViewController = mainSB.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
self.window?.rootViewController = initialVC
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

When the login is successful, I receive a http status code of 200. When that happens, I want to be able to dismiss the login view controller. Has anyone encountered this issue before? Please help! Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you want your login view controller as you `rootViewController`. I would make that your main view controller, and then present your login controller on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

**Once you set your `rootViewController`, you don't want to be dismissing it.**

Therefore I would recommend setting the `rootViewController` to the main view controller (the one that contains the main app interface).

Then in `viewDidLoad` you can just present your `LoginViewController`, using `presentViewController()`, and dismiss after login, allowing you to pass back the login data to the main view controller.